# What does the type of "+" mean in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

My lecture slide says that

```
a -> a -> a
```

means a function take two parameters and return one, and all of them are the same type. Which two are the parameters and which one is the return value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some levels you have to master here:

### level 0

```
a -> b -> c
```

is a function taking one `a` and one `b` and producing one `c`

### level 1

well there is more to it:

```
a -> b -> c
```

which is really

```
a -> (b -> c)
```

is a function taking one `a` and producing another function, that takes a `b` and produces a `c`

### level 2

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

Adds a constraint to `a` (here `Num` - this means that `a` should be a number - `a` is an instance of the `Num` type-class)

So you get a function that takes an `a` and produces a function that takes another `a` and returns a `a`, and `a` needs to be an instance of `Num`

so every input to `f` has to be of the same type of number:

- `f 1 2` is ok
- `f 'a' 'b'` is **not ok**
- `f (1::Int) (2::Int)` is ok
- `f (1::Float) (2::Float)` is ok
- `f (1::Int) (2::Float)` is **not ok**

### level 3 (understanding `(+)`)

The last thing you have to understand here is that, `(+)` is defined as a part of `Num` so there are *different* `+` based on the used types ... and the same is true for the number literals like `0`, `1`, ... thats why `0` can be a `Float` or a `Int` or whatever type that is a instance of `Num`

Comment: And the "=>" means the production of the function is a type of "Num"?

Comment: @user3928256: No. `Num a => ...` means that **`a`** on the right hand side of `=>` must be an instance of `Num`. Have a look at `isPositive :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool`. The input must be some kind of number (`Num a`), and we need to be able to compare that number to `0` (`Ord a`). But the result of `isPositive` is a `Bool`, which isn't a `Num`.

Comment: @Zeta So "Num a => a -> b" means "a" should be the type of "Num" however "b" can be any type?

Comment: @user3928256 yes - but you would say "`a` needs to be an instance of `Num`" - the type can still be any type, as long as it is such an instance.

Comment: You can think of it this way: 0 is a Integer, so is 2, 0.2 is a Float and so is 0.44 and Integer and Float are instances of Numbers - typeclasses say something about the types not about the values of those

Answer (score 1):

The first two are parameters, the last one is the return value.

In fact, due to currying, it can be read like this: the `+` function (which only accepts numeric values) takes a parameter `a` and **returns a function** that takes a parameter of the same type and returns the result of the same type.

Here's a contrived example:

```
let addTwo = (+) 2 -- the + function takes one argument and returns a function
addTwo 3 -- we can add the second argument here and obtain 5 as returned value
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a type like this:

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e
```

The *last* thing in the sequence is the return type. So this function returns something of type `e`. Everything else is the argument types. So this function takes 4 arguments, who's types are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Lower-case letters denote "type variables" — variables which can stand for any type. (It doesn't have to be a single letter, but it often is.) Anything beginning with an upper-case letter is a specific type, not a variable. (For example, `Int` is a type, `int` is a type variable.)

The `Num a` part means that `a` stands for any type, but that type must implement the `Num` type-class. Other common contexts are `Eq` (defines the `==` operator), `Ord` (defines `<`, `>`, and so forth) and `Show` (defines the `show` function that converts stuff into a string).